# Cargar codigo javascript desde XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript

Estoy cargando contenido en un div con XMLHttpRequest, pero quiero ejecutar codigo javascript puro para cambiar el contenido de otro div. Antes funcionaba con jquery y era muy sencillo, pero no lo he logrado con javascript puro.

```
 var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
 function alertContents() {

    if (req.readyState == 4) {
        if (req.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById('insertar').innerHTML = req.responseText;
        } 
    }
}
```

El contenido html, textos y esas cosas se cargan pero ejecuto un simple alert(); dentro de las etiquetas script y nada. Que solucion pueden darme?

Comment: Debes agregar un `callback` a tu codigo si deses ejecutar algo luego de terminar la llamada xmlhttprequest si es ello lo que deseas.... si es usar codigo traido en la respuesta es con `eval()`

Answer (score 0):

Lo solucione por ahora colocando variables dentro de las etiquetas script y ubicando las variables con indexOf. Luego ejecuto javascript con lo valores que obtengo del XMLHttprequest. No es lo mas eficiente pero por ahora me soluciona el problema.
Coloco algo medio explicativo:

```
<script>
    var tabla_mostrar = document.getElementById("tabla_mostrar");

    var var_recibida_request = "<script>var variableEnviada='valor-';</script><table></table>";

          tabla_insertar.innerHTML =  var_recibida_request ;

    var inicio = var_recibida_request.indexOf("variableEnviada");

    var fin = var_recibida_request.indexOf("-");

    var var_para_crear_script = var_recibida_request.substring(inicio, fin);
</script>
```